# Startup Applications not running in Remote Session

Tags: login, autostart, xrdp, xdg

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 with XRDP and I have startup applications. The startup applications run when it's on the computer itself but, the startup applications don't start when it's a remote session. I've placed the startup via the /etc/xdg/autostart and through the remote session, the startup is showing in the "Startup Applications" window. Any idea why it isn't starting up in the remote session?

[image: Startup Application Window via the Remote Session]

As you can see, the program, OutputScreenlet is in it yet, it doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone is also experiencing this problem, apparently it's related to using the Unity Desktop Environment with XRDP, if I use another Desktop Environment, the autostart works. I've just decided to use XFCE instead of Unity.